# Outlook 365 - Filter messages based on sender's group membership

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I would like to be able to filter incoming messages based on if the *sender* is part of a common DL with me.  If this is not possible, I would also be willing to specify which DLs to check the *sender* against.  Outlook seems to provide most filtering around the recipient, with respect to DLs.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the Microsoft 365 distribution group?

If so, according to my research, we cannot filter such emails. In addition, I also try to create a rule, but it can only work on conditions like "Sender is in All Distribution Lists Address Book". I'm afraid your request cannot be satisfied.